# Django Table2 get value Bound Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я немного запутался, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне в  **Table.render_foo methods** получить значение связанного поля `Term_Implementation`?

[Table.render_foo methods](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html)

[BoundColumns](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/internal.html)

```
class EvensList(IncidentsTable, tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = AkpEvents
        
        sequence = ('Term_Implementation', 'Status')

    Term_Implementation = tables.DateColumn(empty_values=(),)

    Status = tables.Column(empty_values=(),)

   def render_Status(self, value, column, columns):
        if value == 'Выполнено':
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-success'}}

        elif value == 'В работе':
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-warning'}}

        elif columns['Term_Implementation'] <= date.today():
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-danger'}}

        else:
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': ''}}

        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно было всего лишь воспользоваться встроенным параметром функции `record`, которая возвращает весь объект.

```
def render_Status(self, value, record, column):
    if value == 'Выполнено':
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-success text-center align-middle'}}

    elif value == 'В работе':
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-warning text-center align-middle'}}

    elif record.Term_Implementation <= date.today():
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-danger text-center align-middle'}}

    else:
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'text-center align-middle'}}

    return value
```